# sqlalchemy encoding - access table from other applications

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, sqlalchemy

I am using *SQLAlchemy* to read some data from a utf-8 encoded file and put them into MySQL database. Everything works fine as long as I am using sqlalchemy to access the data - encoding is perfectly correct in this case.

My problem is that I need to access same data from another app which is not written in python. In this case encoding is not working properly. When I am viewing it through mysql client it is also incorrect.

Could anyone help me figure out a solution?

Comment: You should figure out: 1) what is the encoding of the mysql database,  2) what is the encoding of the data (are you reading it as utf8?) 3) what is the sqlalchemy connection talking (see @pedro's answer) 4) what format/encoding is the data in the database.  Once you figure out what formats everything is in/talking, you can share that and as how to fix the legacy data an how to proceed forward with a single data encoding type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must verify that your configuration meets the following conditions:

- Your MySQL database is configured to use **UTF-8** for tables and columns.
- **ALL** client connections are configured to use **UTF-8**. For [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=tables#unicode) this can be achieved with:

  ```
  # set client encoding to utf8; all strings come back as unicode
  create_engine('mysql+mysqldb:///mydb?charset=utf8')
  ```
- You use `Unicode` for the types of the *SQLAlchemy* columns and **not** `String`.

If the above conditions are met and, again, you make sure that all client connections are configured to use the **UTF-8** character set, and all clients are decoding the UTF-8 byte strings into whatever internal Unicode representation the language in which they are implemented uses (the driver/connector should take care of this automatically if correctly configured) you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Perfect! It did it I wasn't configuring my connection properly. Thank you a lot!